# Background img zoom iOS

Tags: ios, css

I'm a junior web developer and having a problem with my banner background image not displaying properly on ios devices.  Here is my CSS

```css
.banner-section {
  height: 100vh;
  background: url('../assets/img/paul_bh.png') no-repeat center center fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  position: relative;
  color: var(--leo-blue);
}
```

Is there any fix for this, thanks in advance, the repo and gh-pages are below..

https://github.com/alsmith808/leonid

https://alsmith808.github.io/leonid/

Comment: Is it not showing at all on iOS devices or what is the issue you are seeing?

Comment: Its showing, but because its so zoomed in it appears like a solid black background.  Its a black/white image of a guy with headphones on, appears fine on android, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Just a thought, maybe try adding:

```
display: -webkit-box; 
display: -moz-box;       
display: -ms-flexbox;     
display: -webkit-flex;     
display: flex;
```

I was reading up on it here: https://css-tricks.com/using-flexbox/